# Intern : how to check a value is present in an array?

Tags: assert, chai, intern

I'm using intern for the unit test and I have an array like,

```
var arr = ['a','b','c']
```

Now, how to check 'b' is present in arr?

I'm looking for something like, assert.isExistsInArray(), but I don't see any method in the API to check a value is inside the array. However, there is a method `assert.isArray()` - to check the value is in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chai assert API for checking if something is included in an array is [include](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#include):

```
assert.include(arr, 'b');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do an `arr.indexOf('b')` call and assert that the result `>=0`